# Serious social interaction

Tags: plugins, facebook, twitter

I have an old blog... 25 posts on wp 2.6. good content, valuable information, right to the point. I am about to update the blog and the posts. Make the posts more up-to-date (there are some 3 years old, and still new!) and repost it to media sites and create a buzz around this really good information. So the question is...

What, if you build a new site TODAY (wp 3.3) and have good content to post... over the years... what will be your strategy/plugin/toolbox to get the info OUT THERE...

I have tried wordbooker (to publish on facebook) which is always broken... and really bad to use... I have heard of dlvr.it, which seems promising. Twitter feed auto publish and anything and everything.

I would like to know the basic plugin toolset to get the info into the social media and rate good on : http://marketing.grader.com/

I would like to know your experience, your success, your fails... and the good news is, I will apply it RIGHT NOW

Comment: A little search drive me to the obvious social plugin by blogplay, and addthis. Both of them i have used. It add button to share, but dont AUTOPUBLISH anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will migrate the blog to wp 3.1, and add "add this". the others solutions is no reliable !